# ORACLE AUDIT_TRAIL

Tags: sql, oracle

What should be done to enable the system to observe users?
I try

```
alter system set audit_trail=db,extended scope=spfile;
```

but when I check

```
select * from sys.dba_audit_trail;
```

there is no rows selected.

Comment: Please define what 'observe users' mean: you need to give maximum of details about what exactly you want to audit.

Answer (score 0):

In general you need to use the AUDIT statement which a specific SQL statement.

For versions older than 12, you need to use [AUDIT (traditional auditing)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4007.htm#SQLRF01107) and for newer versions you should use [AUDIT (Unified auditing)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4008.htm#SQLRF56110).

Answer (score 0):

Auditing is a large topic within Oracle. You've enabled it with your initialization parameter setting, but you still need to tell Oracle exactly which activity you want to monitor.

Here is a "Getting Started" guide to auditing that should help:

- https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/auditing.htm#DBSEG1023

And some additional references on best practices and features:

- http://www.petefinnigan.com/UKOUG-Build-Practical-Audit-Trails.pdf
- https://pmdba.wordpress.com/2020/03/10/auditing-by-the-numbers/
- https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/auditing-enhancements-12cr1